# Moving arm front and back looks weird

Tags: modeling, bones, weight-painting

I'm trying to make an player model for a TPS. I'm trying to make the character's arm go front and back without it looking weird. I'm not good at weight painting. I'm using this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAO4C_8y0w8), but converted to T-pose, but I also have a A-pose version of the same model too. Do you know any good tutorials for lowpoly models fit for TPS movements
[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use rigify and auto weighting?

Comment: maybe try to extend the weight painting a bit to the shoulders? If it is still not good, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/